# Must all feats granted by the Holy Tactician's Tactical Acumen ability be teamwork feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

I understand the first feat granted by the Paladin [Holy Tactician archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo---paladin-archetypes/holy-tactician)'s [Tactical Acumen](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo---paladin-archetypes/holy-tactician#TOC-Tactical-Acumen-Ex-) extraordinary ability must be a teamwork feat, but are the other feats it grants later under the same restriction, or can you choose any feat after the first?

> **Tactical Acumen**
>
> At 3rd level, a holy tactician gains a teamwork feat as a bonus feat. […] She gains an additional bonus feat for every four levels attained after 3rd, to a maximum of five bonus feats at 19th level. […]

Comment: While I agree with Ozymandias's position, it's usually a good idea to wait a day or so before accepting an answer to see if other differing opinions arise. Accepting an answer often discourages further responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would usually be called out in an ability like this if you could take non-Teamwork feats.

As written, you could argue that they don't have to be Teamwork feats, but I think it's pretty clear that the intent is that they must be Teamwork feats. A Tactician will rely on these bonus Teamwork feats, it wouldn't make sense to allow such a character to choose Skill Focus (for example) instead.

Comment: Alright I appreciate the response just trying to figure out how to make my first character the best I can